# Undefined function within Monologger\Logger class (addCritical function)

Tags: php, linux, monolog

I'm following this monolog tutorial and the example with trying to send a critical log via email using Swift. [monolog+swift_tutorial](https://stackify.com/php-monolog-tutorial/)

i've copied the code exactly, which is located under heading **Handler order** in the tutorial link. I've changed the username and password and email information to my gmail account to send an email to myself etc. However i recieve this error with this statement:

> $logger->addCritical('Hey, a critical log entry!');

And recieve the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Monolog\Logger::addCritical()

I'm using Monolog version: "^2" in my composer.json

So this means the function doesn't exist, so i searched for the function in google, and found other examples of people using this method for their monolog instances, however when i try to use it, as the tutorial shows, i receive undefined method. Could this be an issue with my monolog version? I've also updated everything with composer.

Comment: It looks like it exists in [v1.x](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/1.x/src/Monolog/Logger.php), but not [v2/master](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Logger.php)

Comment: @aynber thank you for finding out, is there a way to use the function, or is there an alternative function for v2?

Comment: Try `$logger->critical('Hey, a critical log entry!');` From their GitHub page, it looks like that should work.